# Entity Framework 4.1 eager loading - on abstract classes

Tags: entity-framework, eager-loading

I'm using EF 4.1 at Code First approach.
I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Base
{
}
```

And two dereived classes:

```
public Class Derived1 : Base
{
     public Division division{ get; set; }
}

public Class Derived2 : Base
{
     public Brand brand{ get; set; }
}
```

At last, I have a query that selects a list of the Base class, and i want to perform eager loading, but i don't know who my derived classes are:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
     var lst = db.Base.Include(WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE).ToList();
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You must do this:

```
var lst = db.Base.OfType<Derived1>().Include(d => division)
            .Union(
               db.Base.OfType<Derived2>().Include(d => d.brand))
            .ToList();
```