# How can I use Include method in entity framework 4.3 for an abstract type?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I have an Order class which links to a list of OrderLine, which is an abstract type.

I want to issue an Include on one of the sub-classes of OrderLine, such as ProductOrderLine which has a Product property on it:

Something like:

```
data.Orders.Include(x=>x.Lines).Include("Lines.Product");
```

Obviously that causes a failure, so I need a way of specifying sub-types I guess.

Thanks

Comment: try this old post ["StackOverflow Post"][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042508/entity-framework-4-1-eager-loading-on-abstract-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including on inheritance hierarchies is [not supported](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-include-property-of-derived-classes). You can only include properties from the base type.